# Is "Shark is chasing the blood" Correct?

Tags: word-usage

When sharks smell blood in water, they follow the blood to find the source. How would I describe this action? I came up with:

> A shark is chasing the blood.

Would a usage like this be correct?

Comment: I might use the word "seeking" which implies that the shark can't necessarily see the blood, but it has an idea of where it is. "Chasing" wouldn't be a bad choice either, though.

Comment: I might use "following" rather than "chasing." One doesn't "chase" a scent, but one can "follow" a scent. A shark may chase or pursue its prey, but I wouldn't regard that the same as chasing the blood. Maybe others will suggest better alternatives.

Comment: I'd agree with J.R. usually you chase something that is trying to evade capture. Chasing an inanimate object (like blood) doesn't ring true.

Comment: Are you describing a specific instance of this happening? or the fact that this happens in general?

Answer (score 3):

To communicate the fact that the shark is targeting the blood as a destination and striving to get closer to it with each turn, I'd recommend either the phrasal verb **"home in on"** (like a homing pigeon or heat-seeking missile) or **"zero in (on)"**, such as

> To converge intently; close in: 
>   
> *The children zeroed in on the display of toys in the store window.*
>   
> ([Source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/zero+in))

Your sentence could be written as:

> **Sharks home in on blood.**
> *(This would describe the phenomenon in general)*

or:

> **A shark zeroes in on the blood.**
> *(This would describe a specific occurrence)*

*(There's nothing special about associating one of these phrasal verbs with one or another way of describing these elements, I just wanted to show a couple of different ways it could be written.)*

---

You could also use "sniff out", which [means](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sniff+out) "to locate someone or **something** by sniffing **or as if by sniffing.**", making your sentence:

> **A shark will sniff out the blood.**

---

*Your choice will depend largely on context. If you describe what else is happening in nearby writing, where you are writing this, who the audience will be, etc., we may be able to provide better help.*

Answer (score 1):

**You can say:**
A shark follows the blood.
The shark is seeking the blood. *(Only if you're writing about a specific shark)*
*(Similar to Sentence 1)* Sharks follow blood to find the source. 
Sharks seek blood. *(This sentence is more concise)*

Answer (score 0):

**How about saying:**

> A shark is after the blood.

It doesn't actually define the part where shark finds the source, but pretty much indicates that **it follows the blood** or, in another meaning, **it has an eagerness for blood**.

Feel free to correct me if I am using it wrong.